# Special SELECT in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have some number like this:

```
1422
1323
4343
2343
and etc.
```

I want to use SELECT Clause in SQL Server to get these number like this:

```
-----------
ColumnName |
-----------
1422       |
-----------
1323       |
-----------
4343       |
-----------
2343       |
-----------
```

Comment: What order does that query follow? I mean, 1422 >1323, but 1323<4343 and 4343>2343. 
Explain what kind of query you want or your intention to get that!

Comment: ok. what is the logic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not asking you why you need this, but you can use a conditional ordering in your `ORDER BY` clause. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [value] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES (1422)
      ,(1323)
      ,(4343)
      ,(2343);

SELECT [value]
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY CASE [value] 
              WHEN 1422 THEN 1
              WHEN 1323 THEN 2
              WHEN 4343 THEN 3
              WHEN 2343 THEN 4
        END;
```

[image]

In your real data you might want to calculated the ordering value in advanced. For example using an `UPDATE` statement and setting how to order groups of values. You can add more `CASE WHEN` statements, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @data nvarchar(max)='1422, 1323, 4343, 2343,4515,7898,4784,4775,4115'

DECLARE @Tempdata AS TABLE (data nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @Tempdata
SELECT @data
SELECT LTRIM(Split.a.value('.','nvarchar(100)')) AS data
FROM(
SELECT CAST('<S>'+ REPLACE(data,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML) AS data 
FROM @Tempdata 
) AS A
CROSS APPLY data.nodes('S') AS Split (a)
```